# SSH works but tunneling or SFTP doesn't. Why?

Tags: centos, ssh, iptables, selinux, tunneling

since 2014 I've got a server from SoYouStart, with Centos 7. It worked perfectly, but now I had to install again the OS. 
Now I'm configuring all the services to work again. 
I need to connect to the server with SSH tunneling to Mysql (now MariaDB) and transfer files with SFTP.
The problem is that I can successfully connect with SSH to the server (from any host) but when I try to use Cyberduck or Navicat to connect to the server using SSH tunneling I get an error ("Server unexpectedly closed network connection" or "There was a problem while connecting to the server on port 22.").
I tried from iPhone with a SSH shell, and I can connect successfully both with SSH and SFTP, but non to the DB with SSH tunneling. 
I cannot understand where is the problem.
I already disabled iptables, firewalld (I replaced it with iptables) and selinux
Connecting directly to the DB allowing remote connection works.
The server has a static ip address, from the provider, and my homework netwkor didn't change during last hours so I don't think the problem is here.

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much

Andrea

---

edit @TheCompWiz

sshd_config already allows Tcp Forwarding. These are the uncommented lines:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
AllowTcpForwarding yes
X11Forwarding yes
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
PermitTunnel yes
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

And it's strange that I can do sftp from a mobile app but I can't do from the computer.. Mysql SSH tunneling still doesn't work

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you have a look into error log from ssh, usually `/var/log/secure` or journalctl for some fatal errors or things that can crash openssh?

If there will be some, can you try to turn on the DEBUG3 logging and post the results in log to see what is going on under the hood?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally had to change OS
I restored centOS 6.6 instead of 7.1 and it works now 
It may be some sort of new protection in 7.1 version which I don't know...
Thanks you all for your support!

Answer (score 3):

ssh tunneling is configured by the ssh-daemon itself.  If the SSH daemon does not permit tunneling, you'll need to re-configure it.  Typically, it's just running openssh server... and you can edit the /etc/ssh/sshd_config and add `AllowTcpForwarding yes` (remove `AllowTcpForwarding no`) and reload sshd config.

As far as sftp goes, this is a slightly different animal.  Essentially, when you want to sftp, the connection starts as a ssh session with a flag that says you want to start the sftp subsystem.  This starts the ssh session as you would expect, but instead of starting a command interpreter, it starts the sftp server, and input/output is directed through the ssh session to/from the sftp-server process.  If no sftp subsystem is configured, or no sftp-server exists, or even if the sftp server isn't configured to permit the user... the whole thing can fail.  Alternatively, you could try `scp` instead, which does not rely on a separate sftp-server subsystem.

Comment: Thank  you very much  for your answer .. I already tried that.. I added some details of sshd_config at the top